# Raspberry Pi Speedometer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am using a raspberry pi to track information from an animals running wheel such as distance travelled and speed.

I am using a script (source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kKWoHWWLt008tQB-H_9C2gjgoBFygKR4/view?usp=sharing)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#get current data from file
file = open("/home/pi/current_count","r")
feet_traveled = float(file.readline())
high_mph = float(file.readline())
max_mph_time = file.readline()

prev_time = 0
mark_time = 0
prev_feet_traveled = 0
mph = 0

def increase_count(channel):
    global prev_time
    global feet_traveled
    global prev_feet_traveled
    global high_mph
    global max_mph_time
    global mph

    feet_traveled += 2.095
    mark_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = mark_time - prev_time
    prev_time = mark_time
    fps = (feet_traveled - prev_feet_traveled) / elapsed_time
    prev_feet_traveled = feet_traveled
    mph = fps / 0.6818182

    if mph > high_mph:
        high_mph = mph
        max_mph_time = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

    print 'Feet per second  = ' + str(fps)
    print 'MPH = ' + str(mph)
    print 'Highest MPH ' + str(high_mph)

    # write mph log
    with open('/home/pi/mph_log', 'a+') as writer:
       localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
       mph_log = localtime + ' MPH {0} fps {1}'.format(mph,fps) + '\n'
       writer.write(mph_log)

GPIO.add_event_detect(6, GPIO.RISING, callback=increase_count, bouncetime=300)

while True:
    miles_traveled = float(feet_traveled)/5280
    print "Distance traveled is {0:,.1f} feet or {1:.3f} miles".format(feet_traveled,miles_traveled)
    sleep(10)
    distance = "<h1>Distance traveled is {0:,.1f} feet or {1:.3f} miles".format(feet_traveled,miles_traveled)
    max_mph = '<h1>Peak MPH was {0:.2f} at '.format(high_mph) + str(max_mph_time)
    current_mph = '<h1>Last speed measured was {0:.2f}mph'.format(mph) 

    # write web page
    with open('/var/www/html/index.html', 'w') as writer:
       writer.write('<html><body>' + distance)
       writer.write('</h1>')
       writer.write(current_mph)
       writer.write('</h1>')
       writer.write(max_mph + '</body></html>')

    # write current count to disk
    with open('/home/pi/current_count', 'w') as writer:
       writer.write(str(feet_traveled) + '\n')
       writer.write(str(high_mph) + '\n')
       writer.write(max_mph_time)

    # write to log file
    with open('/home/pi/log_file', 'a+') as writer:
       localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
       distance = localtime + ' Distance traveled is {0:,.1f} feet or {1:.3f} miles'.format(feet_traveled,miles_traveled) + '\n'
       writer.write(distance)
```

I get the following error when running the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/wheel.py", line
> 55, in 
> miles_traveled =  float (feet_traveled) / 5280 NameError: name 'feet_traveled' is not defined

In the script I have feet_traveled defined as 2.09 because that is the distance traveled during one wheel rotation.

I am not sure why I am getting the error but any help is appreciated.

credit for writing original script: https://www.reddit.com/r/RASPBERRY_PI_PROJECTS/comments/g4xkrd/made_a_speedometer_odometer_for_my_cat_wheel/

Comment: You've only defined `miles_traveled` within the `increase_count()` function. Global variables are generally a sign of bad code, so instead of using them, pass the appropriate parameters to the function and return the appropriate values at the end as a list, tuple, dict, or whatever your favorite data structure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi `feet_traveled` it's only defined and living inside the `increase_count()` function. Consider returning it if you need it outside of the scope of the function.

---

**EDIT**

The point is that the `feet_traveled` variable is indeed defined as global and it will be available outside of the function's scope as well, but you are only *updating* the variable:

```
feet_traveled += 2.095
```

without having it initialized first. You are adding 2.095 to something that can even not be float, in other words.
So my advice is: initialize the variable with

```
feet_traveled = 2.095
```

and your error will go away.

Comment: I made feet_traveled a global variable within the function, so shouldn't I be able to use it outside of the function?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. 
You are right, but i think the point is that after the `global feet_traveled`, you are only *updating* the variable with `feet_traveled += 2.095`, without having it initialized first. You are adding 2.095 to something that can even not be float. So my advice is: initialize the variable with `feet_traveled = 2.095` or initialize to zero `feet_traveled = 0.0` and then update `feet_traveled += 2.095` if you prefer.

Comment: I'm fixing the above answer accordingly. If the solution works for you please considere to accept the answer :)

Comment: Hello, thank u 4 ur help! I tried what you suggested by creating the variable fee_traveled outside of my function (where all my other variables are defined and equal to 0) and making it equal to 0.  I kept feet_traveled inside the function as: feet_traveled += 2.095. When I ran the script I got the following error:  Distance traveled is 0.0 feet or 0.000 miles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/OGwheelv2.py", line 58, in <module>
    max_mph = '<h1>Peak MPH was {0:.2f} at '.format(high_mph) + str(max_mph_time)
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's all the help i can give simply because i cannot run the code not having a raspberry.

Comment: That's ok! It worked after I commented out some lines of code pertaining to the mph calculation. Thank you!